# How can I debug a Rust program in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, rust, visual-studio-2022

I have created the following `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[workspace]


[package]
name = "my_rust_workspace"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
edition = "2021"
description = "Provides the package"
license = "Apache-2.0"

[dependencies]


[[bin]]
name = "main_executable"
path = "./main.rs"
```

And, the following Rust code:

```
fn main() {
    
    let c1 = 5;
    let c2 = 10;

    let _c3 = c1 + c2;
    let _c4 = 200;
}
```

Then I clicked the right mouse button on the root folder and the following menu popped up:

[image]

When I click ***Configuration Tasks*** the following file opens up:

**tasks.js.jason**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-Rust_workspace - vs2022 debug",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I click ***Add Debug Configuration*** the following menu pops up:

[image]

I selected *Native: Debug Windows executable with native code* and then I see that it leads to another JSON file with similar content:

**launch.vs.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "",
      "projectTarget": "",
      "name": "C:\\git\\Rust_workspace - vs2022 debug"
    },
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "",
      "projectTarget": "",
      "name": "C:\\git\\Rust_workspace - vs2022 debug(1)"
    }
  ]
}
```

But, the thing is, I can't do debugging.

When I press Debug button, I see the following error message:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a GitHub issue for the extension you are using [here](https://github.com/kitamstudios/rust-analyzer.vs/issues/29) and I think you might just need to change which item is being debugged in the top of Visual Studio (choose the .exe option or right click your toml file and selecting debug may work)

> cargo.toml file is not on this list, selecting Exe works or selecting cargo.toml from solution explorer, right click/debug will work but these are not the default behaviors, In c# projects we are used to start debuging from the startup project file.

I can see in your screenshot you have main.rs set as your target, which I think is the problem. You need to switch that just as the linked GitHub issue suggests.

Comment: @user366312 try updating your launch json `name` properties to what your project name is now. I am assuming it's still trying to use your previous name and hence can't find it